# How to find the area using graph points?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

[Graph pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roRJf.jpg)

In this graph , there are eight areas namely A,B,C,D,E,F,G and H.

How to find the area using graph points ?

For example :

(20,50) this point is in the area A so , the answer is A.

Is There any formula for finding the  area using graph points ?

How can I find the area using graph points?

Comment: Yes there is, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking about the areas of these triangles, or are you trying to determine in which region any given point lies?

Comment: @poorvaja the Wikipedia page is quite detailed

Comment: Jaap I want to find region any given point .

Comment: Just check whether x>0, y>0, |x|>2|y|, and 2|x|>|y|. From the combination of the four true/false answers to these tests you can tell which region the point is in. You may also need to check that |x|<50 and |y|<50 to make sure it lies inside the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jaap Scherphuis mentioned in a comment, construct a truth table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
x \gt 0 & y \gt 0 & \lvert x \rvert \gt 2 \lvert y \rvert & \lvert y \rvert \gt 2 \lvert x \rvert & \text{Region} \\
\hline
\text{No} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{F} \\
\text{No} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{E} \\
\text{No} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{G} \\
\text{No} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{!} \\
\text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{H} \\
\text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{A} \\
\text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{G} \\
\text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{!} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{D} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{E} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{C} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{!} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{No} & \text{B} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{Yes} & \text{A} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} & \text{C} \\
\text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{!} \\
\end{array}$$
Note that both $\lvert x \rvert \gt 2 \lvert y \rvert$ and $\lvert y \rvert \gt 2 \lvert x \rvert$ cannot be true at the same time; these are marked with a $\text{!}$ in the region, denoting "impossible".

Also note that a point is within the specified square if and only if $\lvert x \rvert \le 50$ and $\lvert y \rvert \le 50$.

---

Note that the above also includes the origin ($x = 0$, $y = 0$) in region $\text{F}$, and the separation lines $y = \pm 2 x$ and $x = \pm 2 y$ in their respective regions.  Depending on which regions you wish these to belong to, you may want to change some of the rules from $\gt$ to $\ge$, or even add extra checks ($x = 0$, $y = 0$, $x = 2 y$, $x = -2 y$, $y = 2 x$, $y = - 2 x$).

Comment: thank you very much for the answer!!!